# Reopen or still a duplicate?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-request

[Using onboard and dedicated graphics cards simultaneously for mixed performance](https://superuser.com/questions/544982/using-onboard-graphics-card-and-dedicated-graphics-card-for-mixed-performance)

This question was closed as a duplicate assuming the OP wanted to use multiple monitors, and it was edited to clarify that the goal was a hybrid-crossfire type setup but with Nvidia hardware. Can this be reopened? Or, alternately, is it now a duplicate of [Using 2 different graphics cards](https://superuser.com/questions/526525/using-2-different-graphics-cards/)?

Answer (score 3):

[Using onboard graphics card and dedicated graphics card for mixed performance](https://superuser.com/questions/544982/using-onboard-graphics-card-and-dedicated-graphics-card-for-mixed-performance) is definitely NOT a duplicate of [Using 2 different graphics cards](https://superuser.com/questions/526525/using-2-different-graphics-cards/), as what's asked in the lather is (still) unclear to me.

The first one is about increased performance, while [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously) is more about using several monitors at once. So the reason for closing the first question is highly debatable.

I would vote for re-opening the question.